# how to ignore a local folder in a vs.net solution from being updated to TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

how to ignore a local folder in a vs.net solution from being updated to TFS?

I have a web service reference, and I don't want this being saved to the TFS source control.

Each time I check-in, the service folder and its 1000's of files are pre-selected.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `File > Source Control > Change source Control` and choose the folder that you to exclude and unbind the mapping of that folder to your workspace.

Comment: i don't see that folder there, I only see projects/solution folders.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the folder from Source Control. This will also delete the folder on the local file system, so make sure to make a copy of the sources first.However Visual Studio will add the files to Source Control once you add the files to the project again, so it might not work.

Another option, however not sure if it will work, is to [cloak the folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181378%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) in the workspace mapping.